# Check if category belongs to post

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hello I'm trying to make script that show all categories and if category belongs to post this category should be checked with checkbox. My script wont works could you help me please. It shows only one checked category when have to shows two.
[Controller](http://pastebin.com/LmZDtDAF) Category model:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    protected $table= "categories";

    public function posts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }

}
```

Post model

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function categories(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
    }

}
```

catRelation:

```
[{"id":"45","post_id":"132","category_id":"1","created_at":"2014-12-26 20:32:41","updated_at":"2014-12-26 20:32:41"},{"id":"46","post_id":"132","category_id":"3","created_at":"2014-12-26 20:32:41","updated_at":"2014-12-26 20:32:41"}]
```

all categories: `[{"id":"1","name":"Laravel","slug":"laravel","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"},{"id":"3","name":"PHP","slug":"php","created_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category shouldn't ever belong to a post, but rather a post should belong to a category.

I assume `catRelation` is your pivot table. It's worth nothing that you need neither `id`, `created_at` or `updated_at` for this.

Example models:

```
class Post extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $table = 'posts';

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category', 'catRelation', 'category_id');
    }
}

class Category extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post', 'catRelation', 'post_id');
    }
}
```

**Note:** I may have got the final arguments in `belongsToMany` the wrong way around.

Comment: I have one more question. After using Category::with('posts')->get(); how to display in view all categories and check categories which are related with current post id?